# How can I correctly use Groupingby of JDK8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
public Map<Long, List<String>> groupby(){
 List<DTO> lst = getResultFromDB();
 Map<Long, List<DTO>> result = 
                   lst.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingby(DTO:getId));
 return result;
}
class DTO {
 private Long id;
 private String code;
}
```

I want `Map<Long, List<String>>` (the String being `DTO.getCode()`), not `Map<Long, List<DTO>>`. How can I do it?

Comment: Sorry, I want Map<Long, List<String>> not Map<Long, List<DTO>>,the String equals  DTO.getCode().

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Collectors.mapping` to map `code` of `DTO`, in `groupingBy`

```
public Map<Long, List<String>> groupby() {
    List<DTO> lst = getResultFromDB();
    Map<Long, List<String>> result = lst
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DTO::getId, Collectors.mapping(DTO::getCode, Collectors.toList())));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot~ I get it.